# How to join tables on the basis of two columns in Sql-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to databases. Check the [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98de0/2). At the moment I am getting more columns than what I need (check fiddle output).

```
Select 
    Test1.email1,
    Test1.dt1,
    Test2.StepsPerDay,
    Test2.DistancePerDay
From 
    Test1
Inner join 
    Test2 ON Test1.dt1 = Test2.dt2
order by 
    dt1
```

My desired output is

```
╔════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╗
║ Email1 ║    Dt1     ║ StepsPerDay ║ DistancePerDay ║
╠════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╣
║ abc    ║ 2015-01-15 ║         500 ║            100 ║
║ abc    ║ 2015-01-19 ║         600 ║            100 ║
║ xyz    ║ 2015-05-13 ║         200 ║            100 ║
║ xyz    ║ 2015-05-14 ║         200 ║            100 ║
║ xyz    ║ 2015-05-15 ║         200 ║            100 ║
║ xyz    ║ 2015-05-16 ║         200 ║            100 ║
║ xyz    ║ 2015-05-17 ║         200 ║            100 ║
╚════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: A left join will never return less rows, but perhaps more (depending on table data.)

Comment: In the fiddle output for xyz user I am getting a lot of rows. I dont know why?

Comment: The fiddle has no select, and no data...

Comment: please add a query to the fiddle and this question, otherwise we can't see your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching only dates but not email. See below:

```
Select 
    Test1.email1,
    Test1.dt1,
    Test2.StepsPerDay,
    Test2.DistancePerDay
From Test1
     Inner join Test2
     ON Test1.email1=Test2.email2
     and Test1.dt1 = Test2.dt2
order by dt1
```

Answer (score 1):

Better `JOIN` (thanks dotnetkid), but also a `GROUP BY`:

```
select Test1.email1,
       Test1.dt1,
       SUM(Test2.StepsPerDay) as StepsPerDay,
       SUM(Test2.DistancePerDay) as DistancePerDay
From Test1
   Inner join Test2
     ON Test1.dt1=Test2.dt2
    and Test1.email1 = Test2.email2
group by Test1.email1, Test1.dt1
order by dt1
```

If you also want results for test1 e-mails/dates not found in test2, switch to `LEFT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`.